# How to set up GHCJS project which I can work on in IDEA?

Tags: haskell, intellij-idea, haskell-stack, ghcjs

I am using [IntelliJ Haskell](https://github.com/rikvdkleij/intellij-haskell) which adds Haskell support to IntelliJ IDEA. I believe the plugin only supports stack.

I only found some old ghcjs options for stack which don't seem to work.

So, how to create / set up a new project which compiles to JavaScript via GHCJS **and** can be worked on in IDEA?

Comment: I'd suggest asking this question at https://github.com/Atsky/haskell-idea-plugin/issues